# Not able to connect Selenium IE driver in java

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried the following code

```
package simple_programs1; 

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver; 

public class ClassessandObjects { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub System.setProperty("WebDriver.IE.Driver", "E:\\Softwares\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.39.0\\IEDriverServer.exe"); WebDriver driver = new 
    InternetExplorerDriver(); 
}
```

I have used *IEDriverServer_x64_2.39.0* > *IEDriverServer* , while I am connecting the *driver* using `java` code, the following error is displaying

> type mismatch : cannot convert InternetExplorerDriver to web driver.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: It might be a good idea to review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: package simple_programs1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ClassessandObjects {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 System.setProperty("WebDriver.IE.Driver", "E:\\Softwares\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.39.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver()

   
  
  
 }

}

Comment: when i tried to use Firefox Driver , i am getting the same issue. Please help on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not instantiating the driver anywhere.In addition to that, you need to set the path of the driver as follows. See more [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG/blob/master/src/Tests/TestHelpers/BaseTest.java)

```
package simple_programs1; 

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver; 

public class ClassessandObjects { 
    public  WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\Softwares\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.39.0\\IEDriverServer.exe"); WebDriver driver = new 
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saifur. I will try this code and let you know if i face any issues

Comment: Hi Saifur, While using this WebDriver.IE.Driver argument , i am getting an exception. so i change the webdriver.ie.driver in the argument, it is working. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Krishna Glad it worked for you. Would you accept the answer then?

Comment: Saifur, i have used the above program in my office system (32 bit Win7) the program has initiated the drivers.and executed the program successfully. but i have used the same program in my home (64 bit win7), it is not initiated the drivers . showing the same error message. could you please help on that

Comment: package simple_programs1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ClassessandObjects {

 public WebDriver driver;
 String url = "https://www.google.com/";
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Softwares\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.navigate().to(url);
 }

}

Comment: Saifur, Could you please help on this issue

Comment: i have created the new project and executed the same code in home it was executed successfully. thanks all for your support